# Doctrine ORM: drop all tables without dropping database

Tags: orm, doctrine

I have to work with an existing database (not managed with Doctrine) and I want to use doctrine only for new tables in this db.

is there a way to tell Doctrine to not drop the entire DB on reload but only the models defined in the `yaml` file ?

Answer (score 49):

I know this a very old question, and it appears you are using symfony.

Try:

```
app/console --env=prod doctrine:schema:drop --full-database
```

This will drop all the tables in the DB.

Comment: It will show what will Doctrine do. --force attribute will drop the DB.

Comment: don't use it in production my friends

Answer (score 13):

I this Symfony command to drop all tables:

```
bin/console doctrine:schema:drop --full-database --force
```

I added flag --force after get a caution message.

Answer (score 7):

For Symfony 3:

```
$entityManager = $container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager'); 

$entityManager->getConnection()->getConfiguration()->setSQLLogger(null);

$entityManager->getConnection()->prepare("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;")->execute();

foreach ($entityManager->getConnection()->getSchemaManager()->listTableNames() as $tableNames) {
        $sql = 'DROP TABLE ' . $tableNames;
        $entityManager->getConnection()->prepare($sql)->execute();
}
$entityManager->getConnection()->prepare("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;")->execute();
```

Comment: Also works with TRUNCATE. Useful when Doctrine Fixtures is having trouble purging the database.

Answer (score 5):

My 2 cents, if you want do this via Php:

```
    $em = ....getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();

    $metaData = $em->getMetadataFactory()->getAllMetadata();

    $tool = new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\SchemaTool($em);
    $tool->dropSchema($metaData);
    $tool->createSchema($metaData);
```

This is a bit slow, you can also delete all data from all tables:

```
$em = getContainer()->get('doctrine.dbal.default_connection');

foreach($em->getSchemaManager()->listTableNames() as $tableName)
{
  $em->exec('DELETE FROM ' . $tableName);
}
```

Comment: Your second proposal will fail for any associations because of foreign key constraints

Answer (score 4):

Old question, but adding for a future soul.

Based on [Meezaan-ud-Din's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39041298/1155833) quickly found it for **Zend Framework 3 + Doctrine 2**

```
./vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:schema-tool:drop --full-database -f --dump-sql
```

**Do NOT use in production**

- `orm:schema-tool:drop` to "drop" database
- `--full-database` to wipe out everything in database *which is managed by Doctrine*!
- To execute, you *must* use `--force` (or `-f`)
- `--dump-sql` to show the SQL being executed. May be combined with the `-f` flag.

Complete code for execution found in class: `\Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\SchemaTool\DropCommand`

Answer (score 1):

You can find a task I use to truncate all tables from a db at this gist: https://gist.github.com/1154458

The core code is:

```
        $this->dbh = $connection->getDbh();
        $this->dbh->query(sprintf('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;'));
        $tables = $connection->import->listTables();
        foreach ($tables as $table)
        {
          $this->dbh->query(sprintf('TRUNCATE TABLE %s', $tableName));
        }
        $this->dbh->query(sprintf('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;'));
```

Comment: Outdated and doesn't work in current version of Doctrine.

Answer (score 0):

@ gpilotino Yes, I'm having a similar problem. There seems to be NO WAY to drop and rebuild the database from within PHPUnit, (The future of Symfony testing).

Maybe it's possible in 'lime',I don't know.

So, I am having to write a reverse ->save() function that backs all the data out of the database, and then resets all the sequences so that I can do automated testing.

For those who don't want to follow in my frustration I tried both:

1) using a Task from inside of symfony:

```
  $optionsArray=array();
  $argumentsArray=array();

  $optionsArray[]="--all";
  $optionsArray[]="--and-load";
  $optionsArray[]="--no-confirmation";

  $task = new sfDoctrineBuildTask($configuration->getEventDispatcher(), new sfFormatter());
  $task->run($argumentsArray, $optionsArray);
```

2)Executing it from outside of symfony while inside of PHP:

```
  Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->getCurrentConnection()->close();
  exec('./symfony doctrine:build --all --and-load --no-confirmation');
```

The reason that I closed the connection is that Postgres, MDBOC (my db of choice) will not drop a database that has a connection. Probably is STILL some kind of problem. I tell ya, it's NEVER as easy as the simple tutorials show. And it's even WORSE with microslop products.

Comment: Why would you PHPUnit your actual data? Use fixtures on a temp DB or just fake the data with some Faker().

Answer (score 0):

To run the command `bin/console doctrine:schema:drop --force` from inside another command, try this:

```php
$command = $this->getApplication()->find('doctrine:schema:drop');
$returnCode = $command->run(new ArrayInput(['--force' => true]), $output);
```