# Symfony - Delete and reload all database records for each test

Tags: symfony1, doctrine

From the [Jobeet tutorial](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/08) provided in Symfony website, I found out that I can load fixtures data each time I run unit test by using this script:

```
Doctrine_Core::loadData(sfConfig::get('sf_test_dir').'/fixtures');
```

However, I want to **delete** and **reload** all records from database each time I run a unit test. Currently, I'm doing this manually (Run *symfony doctrine:build --all* before each test). Can someone provided me a correct way to do this?

Comment: This is a duplicate of the thread with this great answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7119887/187273

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the following in my test/bootstrap/unit.php file at the end:

```
$doctrine = new sfDoctrineDropDbTask($configuration->getEventDispatcher(), new sfAnsiColorFormatter());
$doctrine->run(array(), array("--no-confirmation","--env=test"));

$doctrine = new sfDoctrineBuildDbTask($configuration->getEventDispatcher(), new sfAnsiColorFormatter());
$doctrine->run(array(), array("--env=test"));

$doctrine = new sfDoctrineInsertSqlTask($configuration->getEventDispatcher(), new sfAnsiColorFormatter());
$doctrine->run(array(), array("--env=test"));
```

before loading the fixtures in.  This works nicely for me, although it can get slow if you have a large schema and lots of fixtures.  There's some tips over on [the Web Mozarts blog](http://webmozarts.com/2010/03/11/writing-efficient-tests/) about writing efficient tests, and there's a tip about using an sqlite in-memory database to speed it up.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just clear the tables, you can do so by adding empty arrays to your fixtures, then using `Doctrine_Core::loadData(sfConfig::get('sf_test_dir').'/fixtures');`

```
#Tables to emtpy    
User: []
Post: []

#Tables to load fixtures
Country:
  country1:
    name: United Kingdom
  country2:
    name: USA
```

Comment: Note that this won't reset the ID counts, so you'll need to use richsage's method if you need to do that.

Comment: Much faster than dropping, creating, populating entire database. Thanks!